# .NetCore 2.1 API runs fine but the ulr cannot be reached

Tags: api, asp.net-core-2.1

I am just learning .NetCore 2.1 API section. Also, I need to say I do not have experience with API before. 
I found this [tutorial](https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-development-part3/) to study on and I finished the 3rd part but my API does not respond to me. When I enter http://localhost:5000/api/values url to browser the only respond I get is this site is not reachable. How should I look for the mistake here? I would write code here but I have no idea where the defected part is.
Thank you.

launchSettings.json

```
{
"$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false, 
"anonymousAuthentication": true, 
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:56030",
  "sslPort": 44334
}
},
"profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": false,
  "launchUrl": "api/values",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"AccountOwnerServer": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": false,
  "launchUrl": "api/values",
  "applicationUrl": /*"https://localhost:5001;*/"http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }  } }  }
```

startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        LogManager.LoadConfiguration(String.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/nlog.config"));
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.ConfigureCors();
        services.ConfigureIISIntegration();
        services.ConfigureLoggerService();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All
        });

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404
                && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

valuesController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private ILoggerManager _logger;

    public ValuesController(ILoggerManager logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    //GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        _logger.LogInfo("Here is info message from our values controller.");
        _logger.LogDebug("Here is debug message from our values controller.");
        _logger.LogWarn("Here is warn message from our values controller.");
        _logger.LogError("Here is error message from our values controller.");

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }}
```

Comment: You share your code. Firstly, you need to share your route configuration. Secondly, you share your structural folders in your project.

Comment: I hope he problem somewhere here

Comment: Is the app set to launch on port 5000? Right click on Project - Properties - Debug tab and check the `App URL`